# iMac and MacBook Pro Memory Specifications

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, memory

i am about to purchase an iMac mid 2011 2.7 i5 that comes with 4 GB of ram preinstalled. I  also have an mid 2009 macbook pro 13.3 2.26 computer. I wonder if i can install the 4gb ram of the iMac to my MBP?

Is this possible?
If no, why?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple's support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1270#link2) the Mid 2009 MBP has 1066 MHz DDR3 Ram while the Early 2011 iMac has [1333 Mhz DDR3 Ram](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3011). The Pin number is the same.

According to [this thread in the Macrumors forum](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1094690) 1333 DDR3 Ram can be installed on the MBP with DDR3 Ram, but would only be clocked at 1066 MHz.

Comment: Wouldnt it be still a good increase from original 2 gb to 4 gb to the macbook pro?

Comment: By the way, it's mid 2011 series 27 imac

Comment: You will definitively love the increase in performance you'll get from the two additional GB of memory. I suggest that you replace the memory in your MBP completely with the RAM coming from the iMac. The Ram installed on the 21" and the 27" is the same so this doesn't matter. Are you planning to upgrade your iMac to 16GB or why do you want to remove the 4GB it come pre-installed with?

Comment: i am thinking of installing 8 gb ram on 2.7 iMac 27. I mainly use textmate + safari/firefox + sequel editor and sometimes photoshop (to mainly roughly edit files). So i am a web developer :)

Would you suggest going to iMac i7 3.4 way with 8gb of ram? Or would i5 suffice with this task?

Comment: IMO that would be absolute overkill. I use a mid 2009 iMac with a C2D for exactly the same kind of job. I have 4 GB installed on it. Rather than buying a faster processor (I truly believe that an i5 is more than fast enough) I'd spend my money on buying a good external monitor and maybe take the smallest SSD option instead of the HDD.

Comment: Since i live in a country where i can't order customized specs (ich lebe in der Türkei) i will go for a iMac 2.7 i5 with 8gb of ram and put the other ram in the MBP.

Thank you very very much for this invaluable tip mein Freund :) You saved my day